# How to display table in COBOL's SCREEN SECTION?

Tags: cobol

For learning purposes I am trying the following:
I am trying to display a table via COBOL ... I want to define the way it is all displayed in the `SCREEN SECTION`.

Following happens or is supposed to happen - all without multiple screens opening:

```
(1) User enters ENTRY-SCREEN
(2) User has to type in a password (nothing happens there yet ... I am going   
    step by step)
(3) User hits ENTER and gets to the MAIN MENU
    (3.1) User hits "D" --> List of states and abbreviations is displayed
    (3.2) User hits "S" --> User gets to screen where he can look up state-name  
          by entering abbreviation.
(4) By pressing F2 the user can go back to the MAIN MENU
(5) By pressing F1 the user can exit the program
```

My problem is 3.1 without opening a new screen and without having to define a line and column definition for each state.
Is there a way - maybe with a loop or with `THRU` - to make this easier and maybe even define this in the screen section?
Like:

```
PERFORM VARYING counter FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL counter > 50
*<Display the abbreviation and state-name w/o opening new screen>
END-PERFORM.
```

Comment: @peehaa if possible, please edit everything when amending tags

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by defining the line to be displayed in the Screen Section with a variable line number, which itself is defined separately in working-storage.

Using a loop, in the procedure division, you can display each line by adding 1 to your line variable, display the line, and repeat.